# How can I save a String, a Double, and an Integer from the same line using Java Scanner?

Tags: java, string, integer, double

I have a .txt file where each line is formatted like so...

`pizza  very cheesy  12.30  3` (each "item" is separated by a double space)

I tried using `String[] itemInfo = scn.nextLine().split("\s ");` but that creates an array of each item as a String.

I need to save "pizza" and "very cheesy" as *Strings*, 12.30 as a *Double*, and 3 as *Integer*. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Call `scanner.useDelimiter("  ");` before you start reading.  That's TWO space characters between the quotes. That way, your scanner will interpret the double space as the delimiter.

Then you can use `scanner.next()` for each of the name and the description, as well as `scanner.nextDouble()` and `scanner.nextInt()` after that.

Don't forget to use `scanner.nextLine()` to consume the new line at the end of each line of data.

Comment: This works up until the newline character of each line (after the 3 in this case). I've got it looping through the text file with `while (scanner.hasNewLine())` and it seems that `scanner.nextInt()` it is also being fed the next line's first String so it's throwing an error...So if the first word of the next line is "salad", I think `nextInt()` is being fed `"3\nsalad"`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` to extract the rest part of the line. More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)).

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "pizza  very cheesy   12.30        3";
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");

    String name = parts[0];
    int count = Integer.parseInt(parts[parts.length - 1]);
    double price = Double.parseDouble(parts[parts.length - 2]);

    String description = String.join(
            " ", Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 1, parts.length - 2));

    System.out.println("name: " + name +
            "\ndescription: " + description +
            "\nprice: " + price +
            "\ncount: " + count
    );
}
```

Comment: How many items do you expect to have between the first, "pizza", and the last to numbers when you know the items are separated by two spaces, but the description itself isn't? So is it useful to ignore the given delimiter between the parts and then try to fix that mistake by using Arrays.copyOfRange()? I mean, it is still an approach, but a bit weird.